# Bash: Get array Value by User Input

Tags: bash, unix

I want to output an array with filenames and let the user select the file to process.

Currently I have the following:

```
patches=( $(ls $WORKING_DIR/PATCH_*) )
echo "Select available Patch to apply"
for i in "${!patches[@]}"; do
    echo  "$i"":" "${patches[$i]}"
done

echo "Line Number, followed by [ENTER]:"

read seleted_patch

echo "Patch to install:" "${patches[$selected_patch]}"
```

But `_Patch` to `Install_` just outputs the first value of the patches array.
How can I get the value of the array the user enters on the commandline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but it's just a typo.

Try changing the following line:

```
read seleted_patch
```

To:

```
read selected_patch
```

Comment: Omg. Fail. Thanks!

Why it outputs the 1st Value as default?

Comment: It's a good question - I'm not familiar enough with the intricacies of bash arrays - I generally feel that if you're using such advanced shell-scripting features, you're probably better off with a real programming language.  I guess an undefined variable (`$selected_patch` in your code) somehow references the 0-place in the array, but I dunno why.

Comment: Due to the typo `$selected_patch` is empty and `${patches[]}` has the same meaning as `${patches[0]}`

Comment: I guess, except that `${patches[]}` gives: `${patches[]}: bad substitution`

Comment: Ups, sorry. Tested in ksh where both are valid. @develth You are really using bash?

Comment: Thanks for explanation @e.dan.

Comment: @ULick Yip - really ;) Just for small tasks

Answer (score 1):

You may use select (a command exactly designed for that purpose)

```
PS3= "Select available Patch to apply "
select patch in $WORKING_DIR/PATCH_*; do
    echo "Patch to install: $patch"
    break;
done
```

With added handling for out of range selection

```
select patch in $WORKING_DIR/*; do
    if [[ ! $patch ]]; then
        echo "Selection out of range"
        continue
    fi
    if [[ $REPLY = 'q' ]]; then
        echo "Quit selection"
        break
    fi
    echo "Patch to install: $patch"
    break;
done
```